# Values falling into different ranges in R

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals, between

I have a grid `grd` of different ranges like this one:

```
> grd
   count  treshold
1   1      0.01
2   2      0.02
3   3      0.05
4   4      0.10
5   5      0.20
```

and a dataframe `df` like this one:

```
> df
    param   name
1   0.124   Tim
2   0.011   John
3   0.002   Alex
4   0.023   Jessica
5   0.056   Rose
```

I would like to use `grd$treshold` to add another column to the dataframe, `df$bucket` reporting which range the values in `df$param` fall into.

For instance the first value of `param`, 0.124, is higher than treshold, 0.10, then it will fall in count 5. The second one, 0.011, is between 0.01 and 0.02, then it will fall into count 2, and so on.

This is the final result:

```
> df
        param   name      bucket
    1   0.124   Tim         5
    2   0.011   John        2
    3   0.002   Alex        1
    4   0.023   Jessica     3
    5   0.056   Rose        4
```

Comment: See `help("cut")` and `help("findInterval")`.

Comment: Are you sure your assignments are correct? There seem to be 6 "buckets" (<0.01, 0.01-0.02, 0.02-0.05, 0.05-0.10, 0.10-0.20, >0.20).

Comment: You still have some issues ("0.124, is higher than the last treshold, 0.20, then it will fall in count 5." - please review your question and make sure it's clear

Answer (score 2):

A `base` solution with `findInterval()`:

```r
df$bucket <- findInterval(df$param, grd$treshold) + 1

df$bucket
# [1] 5 2 1 3 4
```

---

You can also use a rolling join with `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(grd, by = join_by(closest(param < treshold))) %>%
  select(-treshold)

#   param    name count
# 1 0.124     Tim     5
# 2 0.011    John     2
# 3 0.002    Alex     1
# 4 0.023 Jessica     3
# 5 0.056    Rose     4
```

---

##### Data

```r
grd <- read.table(text = "
count  treshold
1   1      0.01
2   2      0.02
3   3      0.05
4   4      0.10
5   5      0.20")

df <- read.table(text = "
param   name
1   0.124   Tim
2   0.011   John
3   0.002   Alex
4   0.023   Jessica
5   0.056   Rose")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df |> 
  mutate(
    bucket = case_when(
      param <= 0.01 ~ 1,
      param <= 0.02 ~ 2,
      param <= 0.05 ~ 3,
      param <= 0.10 ~ 4,
      param <= 0.20 ~ 5
    )
  )
```

As far as I understood you question, the final result you shared in your question is not correct (row 2). If I misunderstood you can easily adjust the threshold parameters in case_when()

Comment: If there are 100 thresholds, this method needs to hard-code it for 100 times in `case_when`.

Comment: For sure. I thought it was only the ones he mentioned. Might have misunderstood :)